# UITapGestureRecognizer on transparent view

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I have a tree with views where the highest level view is transparent and contains either an image or a label (with a transparent background).

When attaching a UITapGestureRecognizer to this view, I only get notifications on the views which contain images.
Also, if I leave the view empty, then I get events only when the background color is different than [UIColor clearColor].

I have done a dump and the entire view tree has userInteractionEnable = YES.

How can I get the UITapGesturerRecognizer to work on the view with a transparent background?

**Solved**
Problem was not what I thought. The transparent views were in a scroll view and during initialization they were outside of the view's visible area. Those within the visible area work ok.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail or code, I tried attaching a tap gesture recognizer to a view with background color set to clearColor and it responded to taps. So a bit more info could help.

Comment: @DeepakDanduprolu Do tell... Having the same scenario as posted, a UISwipeGestureRecognizer and it won't respond anywhere on the view (with clearColor) EXCEPT where there are other (sibling-) views (not clearColor) behind it! Yes, it is iOS-randomness at it's finest.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background color to whatever except the clearColor and setting the alpha property to 0.0;

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myView.alpha = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guesses here, but if you include a 1x1 pixel image in the view, would that view then qualify for gestures?
Another equally wild guess would be to add a transparent image to the view and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the view a nearly-transparent background color, like `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.01]`.