# GestureRecognizer not responding to tap

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

After initialisation of by subclass of `UIImageView` I have the following line of code:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = true
self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:"))
```

I created the necessary associated function :

```
func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("In handler")
}
```

On tapping on the view in question, "In handler was never printed to the console". I then removed the handler function to see if the compiler would complain about the missing function. It didn't.

I'm positively stumped. I'd truly appreciate any light people can shed on this.

**Update**: My class is actually a `UIImageView` as opposed to `UIView`

Comment: Try `self.view.addGestureRecognizer`  I haven't tried it in Swift, but that is what I use in Objective C.

Comment: That I'm using `self.userInteractionEnabled` implies that these code snippets are actually inside the view I'm interested I modifying. As such, `self.view` is an impossibility! Thanks for contributing all the same!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I discovered the answer after carefully combing through my code.

One of the parent views was created without supplying a `frame:`

While it's a noobish enough error to warrant deletion of this questions, odds are someone else will also have the same issue in the future...

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. What do you mean one of the parent views was created without supplying a frame? How do you do this?

Comment: I had this exact same problem. I had a view with a UIScrollView subview, which had a UIImageView subview. I'd not specified the frame for the UIImageView, and that was preventing the buttons from working. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know why this would cause the gesture recognizer to fail to detect the touch..?

Comment: I am unable to get it. Where I can add this `frame:` for UIImageView?

Comment: Similar to the no frame problem, I just had a UITapGestureRecognizer not work because the view's frame height was too small for the content (even though all of the content appeared in the display just fine). Might be an edge case, but adding this comment in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 143):

I was using `UITapGestureRecognizer` that I placed on a `UILabel` using Storyboard.

To get this to work I also had to place a checkmark in the block labeled: "User Interaction Enabled" in the `UILabel` Attributes Inspector in the Storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's it - forgot about that in the time since I last built an app.  Seems like something that should be automated when you attach the gesture recognizer.

Comment: You just saved my 30 mins.

Comment: I don't understand why the user interaction is disabled by default.

Answer (score 19):

Try this

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func handleTap(sender : UIView) {
    println("Tap Gesture recognized")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the userInterActionEnabled to my UIImageView was the solution in my case.

Comment: It's not good to place it in viewDidAppear since you'll end up with tons of gestures added

Comment: You can add those code in viewDidAppear and then remove gesture recognizers in viewDidDisappear. This will solve infinite number of gesture recognizers added to your view.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the other answers, this can be caused by adding the gesture recognizer to multiple views.  Gesture recognizers are for single views only.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567684/6543020

Comment: Great addition!

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this problem with programmatic views.

My UIView with the gesture recognizer had .isUserInteractionEnabled = true, but it did not respond to taps until I set .isUserInteractionEnabled = true for its parent views as well.

Comment: I'm doing programmatic views and this is what did it for me.

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely you add `UIGestureRecognizer` in wrong place. Here is working sample with `UIView` from `storyboard`. If you create your `UIView` dynamically then you should put this initialization in the correct constructor.

```
class TestView: UIView
{
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:"))
    }

    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("Here")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution to this problem after lot of trial and error. So there are two solution two this

**1.** Either add the `GestureRecognizer` in viewDidLoad() and turn 
   `userInteractionEnabled` = `true`

**2.** If using computed property use `lazy var` instead of `let` to the property.

```
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "gameofthrones_splash")
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return iv
}()
```

Comment: You save my day!

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that is still having problems even with all the previous answers, make sure you are using `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of `UIGestureRecognizer`, I kept missing this detail while trying to find what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**This Code works for me with XCode 7.0.1**

```
import UIKit

class ImageView: UIImageView {

    init(frame: CGRect, sender: Bool, myImage: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.image = myImage
        initBorderStyle(sender)

        // enable user interaction on image.
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "previewImage:")
        addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func previewImage(myGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        print("i'm clicked")
    }

    private func initBorderStyle(sender: Bool) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        self.layer.borderColor = getBorderColor(sender)
        self.backgroundColor = getColor(sender)
    }


    func getBorderColor(sender: Bool) -> CGColor {
        var result: CGColor
        if sender {
            result = UIColor(red: 0.374, green: 0.78125, blue: 0.0234375, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
        } else {
            result = UIColor(red: 0.3125, green: 0.6015625, blue: 0.828125, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode 11.4 Swift 5.2**

`UserInteraction` is enabled by default on Custom `UIView`

```
import UIKit

class YourView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func tapped() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

---

If you want to be notified elsewhere that the custom `UIView` has been tapped, then it is convenient to use a `Notification`.

It is best to create this as an extension to prevent it being Stringly typed.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let DidTapMyView = Notification.Name("DidTapMyView")
}
```

In your custom `UIView` when the tapped `function` is called

```
@objc func tapped() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .DidTapMyView, object: self)
}
```

In your `UIViewController` where you want to listen for the `Notification`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myViewWasTapped), name: .DidTapMyView, object: nil)
}

@objc func myViewWasTapped() {
    // Notified here - do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of my findings in 2021, XCode 13:

- Make sure both your view and all of its superviews have set width & height constraints(this one is crucial)
- Set `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` for your view
- There's no need to set explicit frame or `isUserInteractionEnabled` for other super views

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my gesture didn't work because it was in a normal class, and not a subclass of `UIView` or anything.

I solved the issue by creating a subclass of `UIView` that I had an instance of in this normal class and placed the gesture logic in that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition the above (`userInteractionEnabled`, `clipsToBounds`, etc.), if you are working with a view in a child view controller be sure that you have added it as a child with `myParentViewController.addChild(myChildViewController)` — we've run into a couple of situations now where visible views were not firing recognizing gestures because their view controllers hadn't been added, and presumably the VCs themselves were not being retained.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I had the same issue and was having a hard time debugging. This helped me look at the right place!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by setting the height to the UIView.

```
optionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my programmatically created ViewController. The bug was fixed when I added a backgroundColor to the view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }
}
```

Comment: I wish people would comment when they downvote. As weird as it seems this worked for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010186/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-transparent-view